# I've encountered a bug in Tiny Death Star, what can I do to fix it?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

There have been many different reports of bugs in Tiny Death Star.  As most of them have the same solution, I am asking the following:

How do I fix or get help with bugs in my game of Tiny Death Star?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is very little you can do to modify this game on the user level.

Therefore, there are really only three actions you can take if you are experiencing a bug in game play:

1. **Do nothing:**  For the most part, most of the bugs are annoying but do not affect game play in any significant way.
2. **Attempt a reinstall of the game:**  Before doing this, I would do two things.  First, go to the menu screen, click on the wrench, and click the help tab.  There is a long string of numbers at the top of this screen.  I would record this number.  Next, I would go on to the next option:
3. **Contact Disney Customer Support:**  *support@disneymobile.com*  As in option 2, I would record the individual identifier for your game and send it to them.

Comment: I wish Disney made a bigger presence on the web to support Tiny Death Star, and have forums to allow people to interact and report bugs and feature requests. I hope they frequent this board - lots of great ideas here.

Comment: Yeah.  Their support of this game has been abysmal at best.  They should have let Nimblebit do their own support.  I've heard it was significantly better than that from Disney!

Answer (score 2):

Some other possible approaches I can think of:

1. Quit the app completely (i.e. dismiss it from multitasking screen) and restart. If that doesn't work, restart the device completely.
2. Check to ensure that you have the latest version of the game installed.
3. Try to see if the bug occurs on another device, i.e. borrow a friend's iPad, iPhone or Android device (as appropriate). Could be some obscure bug if you're using a different operating system (i.e. iOS 6 vs 7, Android 4.3 vs 4.4). For Apple devices, I think you can try using iCloud to transfer the save, or manually extract the data directory and copy it over. Not sure if you can do the same on Android. There's no end to these bugs, but if you contact support, at least you can give them as much info as possible if you tried these things before.
4. This is kind of a crummy thing to do, but don't update immediately when it becomes available. Wait a few days and see if anyone reports problems. This is akin to letting other people ferret out the bugs, but it might be preferable to losing your progress.

Bugs are pretty annoying. I feel really bad for those who got stuck with the negative bux bug.

Comment: These are also some very helpful points!